# iOS - Empty translation

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, translation

After editing the exported XLIFF file from Xcode with the right XML structure, when I try to import it back Xcode just shows me a warning saying, "Empty Translation".

I can't seem to find out the issue here - my syntax for the file is correct - each "trans-unit" node has a "source", a "target", and a "note" sub-nodes.

It can even read the translation in the preview: 
[image]

What could be possibly wrong? Any hints?

Comment: Sorry to reavive a +6 years old thread, but did you've managed to fix this? I'm with the same issue.